# Cloudflare » Images missing with 404 error ONLY on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, ssl, cdn, cloudflare

Yesterday, I've installed Cloudflare on my WordPress website [LIKEAD](https://likead.fr). So…

- I have created the account
- Changed the DNS server by Cloudflare server with OVH
- And connected it to my website with WP_Rocket

But here we are : I've managed to make CSS/JS work but there is now a weird problem **only on Chrome**… Images doesn't appear because of a 404 Error… Chrome doesn't find them.

I don't know at all what can cause this error because images appear correctly on Safari and Firefox.

Another weird thing is that when I try to test my website on Google Pagespeed Insight this thing appear :

**A DNS error occurred during the resolution of likead.fr. Check the spelling of the host, and make sure the page is accessible from the public Internet.**

[Here is my DNS records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEU4S.png)

My website uses SSL. Could it be a problem with Cloudflare and the use of the SSL certificate on all my URLs ?

I don't know at all what caused this dysfunction… 
If you have an idea, I would be grateful. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Photon feature on your Jetpack plugin. Or just disable that plugin will fix the problem :)

And show me your DNS record on Cloudflare please. I can't connect to your site due to `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

Comment: Hello ! So I remove Jetpack plugin and you were right. It worked :) I have also edit my post to add an image of my DNS records. Again, thank you for your help !

Comment: You should add an A record, name = @, value is your hosting/VPS IP. Add another CNAME record, name = www, value is `@`. It will work :)

Comment: Doesn't work :(
Google Pagespeed can see the website but OVH put automatically a redirection to http://imp.ovh.net/ 
PS: I've actualise the images of my DNS records

Comment: Now I can visit your website, and check your Pagespeed score too. Your website: (http://i.imgur.com/lCbsMRl.png), your Pagespeed score: (http://i.imgur.com/vBfESWL.png). You can flush your DNS cache to test again.

Comment: It seems to came from my DNS server on OVH. I've remove my originals servers to put those of Cloudflare. Isn't that what I had to do? Thank you

Comment: Just update your nameserver on OVH to ajay.ns.cloudflare.com and liv.ns.cloudflare.com, instead of default OVH's nameserver. And as I see, you are complete everything and no need to worry about malfunction or redirection. I think its your DNS cache problem from your computer. Pingdom can connect too :) https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cMghOE/likead.fr

Comment: Well… Google Pagespeed show me error but it seems to work on my others computers. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Now you can try reinstall Jetpack and turn on Photon if you want to save some bandwidth :P Read more: https://jetpack.com/support/photon/

Answer (score 0):

You must have gotten it resolved, because I can see images at https://likead.fr/ Nicely done! The problem is because of **PHOTON** Servers were not responded for your domain.

Original Image

> https://likead.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/sandra-min.jpg

Photon Image

> https://i1.wp.com/likead.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/sandra-min.jpg